# Using global variables in defining small functions, should I avoid and what are the options?

Tags: global-variables, common-lisp

I wrote a program which turns a number into binary form  in a list of distinct ones and zeroes. I find myself using global variables, `(defvar lis '())`, which feels sort of unnecessary and not elegant. Is it a taboo to use global variables in lisp for a program like mine? And what can I implement instead of them?

```
(defun exp2 (x &optional (i 1))
  (if (< 0 x)
      (exp2 (1- x) (* i 2))
      i))

(defvar lis '())
(defun make-binary (x &optional (y 8)) 
  (if (< y 0) 
    lis
    (if (<= (exp2 y) x)
        (progn 
            (setq lis (append lis '(1)))
            (make-binary (- x (exp2 y)) (1- y)))
        (progn
            (setq lis (append lis '(0)))
            (make-binary x (1- y))))))
```

Thanks you for your time!

Comment: Maybe you want to use the function MAKE-BINARY more than one time? Plus: never ever append something to the end of a singly-linked list -> that makes your programs slow.

Comment: Note also that the language is called Common Lisp, not C-LISP or CLISP.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it a taboo to use global variables in lisp for a program like mine?

It is a source of problems in all languages:

- in a multi-threaded environment, you cannot call the same function in parallel, because they act on the same global variable, making the program incorrect or non-deterministic
- even in a single-threaded environment, there is no upside to using global-variables in cases where local variables work: you make your functions rely on side-effects, and if you have multiple such global variables you have to really be careful about the order of execution of your functions to not mess up the global state.

In particular here:

- you only ever append to `lis`, and never reset it to `nil`, so if you call your function twice, the result will be different (and only the first call will give a correct answer).
- this may work if you only execute the script once and quit your environment, but typically you don't do that, you call functions more than once. Besides, you want to structure your programs in a way that makes your life easier later, when you want to use it or modify it. Limiting the amount of context needed to understand what a function does help you in that aspect.

> And what can I implement instead of them?

You use local variables.

Here your function has basically this pattern:

```
(defun recurse (input output)
  (if (stop input)
      output
      (recurse (new-input input)
               (new-result input output))))
```

You have a recursive call where you carry the result down to the base case `(stop input)`, in which case you return the result (a list of digits); but in order to build that result, in the general case, you combine your input with your output so far, to obtain a new output. More precisely,
you recurse with a new input (typically here, you have a smaller number), and with a new result (here you add a digit in the list).

Answer (score 0):

Your make-binary function can be written using `format`:

```
(defun string2nums (s)
  (mapcar #'digit-char-p (coerce s 'list)))

(defun make-binary (num &optional (y 8))
  (string2nums (format nil (format nil "~~~a,'0B" y) num)))
```

The inner `format` directive puts `y` into the binary directive `~<y>B' and the` ,'0`before the`B` makes the zero padding at the beginning of the string.

Thus said, how I would avoid the global variable which carries the
result is - to add it as a parameter to your function which carries the result to the next recursive call. With this technique,
you can avoid global variables very often in functional programming.

```
(defun exp2 (x &optional (i 1))
  (if (< 0 x)
      (exp2 (1- x) (* i 2))
      i))

;; lis is acc (accumulator of the result)
(defun make-binary (x &optional (acc '()) (y 8))
  (cond ((< y 0) (nreverse acc))
        ((<= (exp2 y) x) (make-binary (- x (exp2 y)) (1- y) (cons 1 acc)))
        (t (make-binary x (1- y) (cons 0 acc)))))
```

This accumuluator-cons-return-nreverse idiom/pattern is very common in recursive functions of common lisp. `nreverse` because it is more memory efficient and faster than `reverse` (the accumulator will get destroyed any way after return, so you can use a destructive function without having any harm from it).